# Uploading PDF file and providing download links to them

Tags: uploads, file-manager

One of my clients has a number of documents in PDF format that he wishes to provide download links to on his site.

One solution I have been toying with is to treat them similar to images and upload them through the media uploader provided with WP and then provide a named link to the file.

I would like to know if the above method is a good way or is there a better way to do this. Moreover, from a maintainability point of view dumping PDF files with images is not exactly the best way to manage these files so it would be good to partition these files into a separate directory.

I am also interested to know if there are any plugins available to do this.

Thanks in advance.

nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method you have described is valid , and technically you can use it without a problem.
Other options you have are :
1.Upload via FTP to a "PDF" folder (or whatever name) and MANUALLY link the files.

1. Change the default "upload" folder only for the time you upload the pdf files (this method is not reccomanded and will work only on a more "static" site where pdf´s are uploaded only once or twice in bulk)
2. as for plugin - there is this one 
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-easy-uploader/screenshots/
   which is a bit old but might help you. (I did not verify if works on current release)
3. write a custom function that will either A: change the upload dir ONLY for PDF (easy to write) or B: Let you choose plugin folder for EACH upload.

Right now I am a bit pressed with time, but if you are interested in option 4 let me know .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It has been most helpful. I think I will have a go at option 3 writing a custom function. Do you mean option 3 not option 4 in your last line?

Comment: yes, Option 3 .-) sorry..

Answer (score 4):

I am using a plugin called download manager. It creates a shortcode for each of the the files you upload, provides a download count and attaches icons to the link so that you see a pdf icon for example, against a file name.

Check out: [Wordpress Plugin Site - Download Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-manager/)